Why does Cepheid Brightness change?
I'm looking for an explanation of the cepheid mechanism. I looked all over the web but, strangely, I found nothing on it (almost nothing).
For the moment, here is what I got :

The theory progressed over the last century, from a binary star system (2 suns rotating around the same gravity point) to a specific matter composition...

The pulsation rests on the Helium ionization (the transparent He2 gas will turn into He3, which is an opaque gas). Step by step we can resume here :
1] The Helium layer is condensed by the gravitation force. Here the temperature increases but, overall, it's the density that increases. This transforms the He2 to He3 (the star becomes opaque)
2] According to Kramer's opacity laws, the opacity is proportional to the density on the temperature. As the density increased quicker than the temperature, the new He3 gaz became opaque.
3] The opaque gas keeps the heat to itself and it takes more and more place
4] This expansion of matter cools down the gas and the He3 turns into He2.
5] The light goes how and we cycle begins again.
The same explanation in a few words is :
Concentration of He2 + Temperature = He3 + Opacity
Opacity = Keep the heat
Heater = Take more space
Take more space/Expansion = Cooling down
Cooling down + He3 = He2 + Transparent layer
And it starts again...
But I'm not confident in my explanation and questions are still remaining. For instance :
Is my summary good? Did I make mistakes?
Does He3 have a bigger density than He2?
Why the star can't reach a balance point?
Is the temperature or the pressure that allows the transformation of He2 to He3?
In a nutshell I ask you to enlighten me and show me my errors (I'm still surprised that no one ever spoke of that topic...)
My Sources :
The Secret lives of cepheid - Section Cepheid Pulsation Mechanism ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.02713 )
The Wikipedia articles in All langages translated in English (the best are : https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%97%D0%B4%D0%B0 )
Thanks a lot
TAGS : K Kappa Mechanism ; Gamma Mechanism ; Eddington Valve ; Cepheid

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepheid_variable#Pulsation_model https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~gk/A403/pulse.pdf https://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/ryden.1/ast162_4/notes16.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappa%E2%80%93mechanism https://iopscience.iop.org/book/mono/978-0-7503-5794-4/chapter/bk978-0-7503-5794-4ch20 https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/ESSAYS/Evans/evans.html

Just the first few hits from googling "Cepheid pulsation mechanism"

Found that to explain the story of the Cepheid mechanism theory (https://app.aavso.org/media/jaavso/2739.pdf)
I will check your articles, thanks!

https://youtu.be/X_3QAB3o4Vw (I found a video of the subject, that strange because I didn't find it with my navigator; I needed to switch of app...)
